How to solve this ODE $y'^2+(y^2)'/x=1$ in a better way?
Strived to solve this ODE, but it seems not be able to work out the the integral after variable substitution.
$$\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^2+2\frac{y}{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=1$$
Let $p=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$, we get
$$
p+\frac{y}{x}=\pm\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}
$$
Then substitute $y=vx\implies p=y'=v+xv'$ to arive at
$$
2v+x\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}=\pm\sqrt{1+v^2}\implies\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{-2v\pm\sqrt{1+v^2}}=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}
$$
where the left integral is far from easy to solve. So probably some one has fancier way to solve the ODE.
PS:
The given solution is $C^2+2Cy(3x^2-y^2)=x^2(x^2-3y^2)^2$.

I don't know if this may help, but $y(x)=\pm\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}$ solves the equation. I just thought of solutions of the form $ax^\lambda$ and for $\lambda=1, \ a=\pm\sqrt{3}$ it works

Yes, it one of the solutions.

So, your solution is given by an implicit equation?

This can also be done using polar coordinates, although there is a tricky trig identity in the middle. Convert the equation
$$
\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+2\frac{y}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$
using $x^2+y^2=r^2$, $\frac{y}{x}=\tan\theta$. Under this transformation to polar coordinates,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{r'\sin\theta+r\cos\theta}{r'\cos\theta-r\sin\theta}$$
We are using $r'$ to mean $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$. So we have
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{r'\sin\theta+r\cos\theta}{r'\cos\theta-r\sin\theta}\right)^2+2\tan\theta\frac{r'\sin\theta+r\cos\theta}{r'\cos\theta-r\sin\theta}&=1
\end{align}$$
After clearing denominators and combining terms by their power of $r'$, you get:
$$\left(r'\right)^2\left(3\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta\right)+(r')2r\tan\theta\left(3\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta\right)+r^2\left(\cos^2\theta-3\sin^2\theta\right)=0$$
Now divide by $\left(3\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta\right)$. Note that this is not a valid step if $3\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta=0$. There are angles that make this happen, $\pm\pi/6$ and $\pm5\pi/6$, and these correspond to the solutions mentioned in the comments $y=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}x$.
$$\left(r'\right)^2+(r')\frac{2r\tan\theta\left(3\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta\right)}{3\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta}-r^2=0$$
Here we apply a non-obvious trig identity:
$$\left(r'\right)^2-2r\tan(3\theta)r'-r^2=0$$
And the quadratic formula:
$$
\begin{align}
r'&=r\tan(3\theta)\pm\sqrt{r^2\tan^2(3\theta)+r^2}\\
r'&=r\left(\tan(3\theta)\pm\sec(3\theta)\right)\\
\frac{r'}{r}&=\tan(3\theta)\pm\sec(3\theta)\\
\ln|r|&=\frac13\ln|\sec(3\theta)|\pm\frac13\ln|\sec(3\theta)+\tan(3\theta)|+C\\
r^3&=k\sec(3\theta)(\sec(3\theta)+\tan(3\theta))^{q}
\end{align}
$$ where $q=\pm1$. This explains a rotational symmetry of order $3$ that the solution curves have. You could expand the trig function using triple angle identities, and then convert back to cartesian coordinates.

An extraordinary approach! Demanding excellent insights. Frankly speaking, I have no clue about this identity $\left(r'\right)^2-2r\tan(3\theta)r'-r^2=0$ at all.

The integral is not so bad:
If you rationalize becames
$$
\int \dfrac{\pm\sqrt{x^2+1}-2x}{3x^2-1} dx
$$
The second addendum can be soved easily while if you substitute $x=\tan(u)$ and $\sin(u)=v$ in the first addendum you obtain
$$
\int \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{3x^2-1} dx=\int \dfrac{\cos(u)}{3\cos^2(u)\sin^2(u)+\cos^4(u)} du=\frac{1}{3}\int \dfrac{1}{1-v^2}dv
$$
Solving this integral and substituting back you obtain the solution.

If you want another method to solve the ODE you can use the fact that this equation is an example of D'Alambert equation.
Let $p=\frac{dy}{dx}\ne 0$. The equation becames, after some algebraic modifications
$$
y=x \left(\frac{1}{2p}-\frac{p}{2}\right)
$$
Let call $\frac{1}{2p} -\frac{p}{2}=f$. Taking the derivative w.r.t. $x$ we have
$$
p=f+x\frac{df}{dp} \frac{dp}{dx}  
$$
or
$$
p-f=xf'\frac{dp}{dx}
$$
You can find the singular solution by imposing $\frac{dp}{dx}=0$ that gives
$$
 \frac{3p^2-1}{2p}=0
$$
The general solution can be found by solving the ODE
$$
\frac{dx}{dp}(p)=\frac{p^2+1}{2(p^2-1)p}x(p)$$
That gives
$$
x(p)=C \left(\dfrac{1-p^2}{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$
That gives
$$
p(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left(-x^2 \pm  \sqrt{x^4+4} \right)
$$
If you are instead only interested in obtaining the solution as an implicit equation you can solve the first equation for $p$, i.e.
$$
p=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2(x)} \pm y(x)}{x}
$$
And substitute this on the formula above

The Wolfram Alpha part was just solving a quadratic equation!

@LL3.14 right, I malfunction for a moment

If you multiply through by $x^2$ and complete the square:
$$
\begin{align}
(xy')^2+2xyy'+y^2&=x^2+y^2\\
\left(xy'+y\right)^2&=x^2+y^2
\end{align}
$$
Now substitute $y=vx$:
$$
\begin{align}
\left(x(v'x+v)+vx\right)^2&=x^2+v^2x^2\\
\left(v'x+2v\right)^2&=1+v^2
\end{align}
$$
Now substitute $v=\tan u$:
$$
\begin{align}
\left(xu'\sec^2u+2\tan u\right)^2&=\sec^2u\\
xu'\sec u+2\sin u&=q
\end{align}
$$
where $q^2=1$. Now with Weierstrass substitution $u=2\arctan(t)$:
$$
\begin{align}
x\frac{2t'}{1-t^2}+\frac{4t}{1+t^2}&=q\\
x\frac{2t'}{1-t^2}&=\left(q-\frac{4t}{1+t^2}\right)\\
\frac{2q(1+t^2)t'}{\left(1-t^2\right)\left(t^2-4qt+1\right)}&=\frac{1}{x}\\
\left(\frac{4t+2q}{t^2-1}-\frac{4t-8q}{t^2-4qt+1}\right)t'&=\frac{3}{x}
\end{align}
$$
In the above, dividing by $t^2-4qt+1$ is only valid for solutions that are not $y=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}x$. Now the integration is now pretty straightforward:
$$
\begin{align}
2\ln\left\lvert t^2-1\right\rvert+q\ln\left\lvert\frac{t-1}{t+1}\right\rvert-2\ln\left\lvert t^2-4qt+1\right\rvert&=3\ln|x|+C\\
\left(\frac{t^2-1}{t^2-4qt+1}\right)^2\left(\frac{t-1}{t+1}\right)^q&=kx^3\\
\end{align}
$$
At this point, examine $q=1$ and $q=-1$ separately:
$$
\begin{align}
(t+1)(t-1)^3&=kx^3\left((t-2)^2-3\right)^2&(t+1)^3(t-1)&=kx^3\left((t+2)^2-3\right)^2
\end{align}
$$
Back substitute $t=\tan(u/2)=\frac{\sec u-1}{\tan u}=\frac{\sqrt{v^2+1}-1}{v}=\frac{\sqrt{(y/x)^2+1}-1}{y/x}=\frac{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}-x}{y}$. This will be a bit tedious and take some algebraic effort to manipulate the equation into the form that you have for the solution.
